# 2023 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election, announcements

The 2023 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://magento.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta – just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: The Community bot didn't automatically make this post like it should have, for some reason – while the devs dig into that, I've manually posted the announcement myself.